# 2 columns pointing to the same foreign field

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1452

I have a mySQL table `messages` with this fields: `id`, `parent`, `profesor`, `message`.

`parent` and `profesor` are both users and are stored in the `user` table (`id`, `name`, `last name`)

So I created the table in phpMyAdmin and then I wrote:

```
alter table messaged add foreign key (profesor) references user (id)
```

and worked perfectly!
when I do the same for the parent, I get this error:

```
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`school`.`#sql-1e30_fe`, CONSTRAINT `#sql-1e30_fe_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`parent`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`))
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your `alter table` command is for the `professor` column, but the error message is about `parent`. Which is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have any data in 'messages' table? If so, all the messages.parent fields should be filled with corresponding values of user.id, otherwise you get this error.

You can check not constraining rows with this query:

```
SELECT id, parent FROM messages WHERE parent NOT IN 
(SELECT id FROM user)
```

Comment: I deleted all data in messages and worked perfectly! thanks!!